# Is it possible to upload an iOS app iPA on iTunes Store without logging in with Apple ID in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, itunes-store

I have an iOS app IPA generated using manual signing that I would like to upload to iTunes Store (via iTunes Connect).

Is it mandatory to login with the Apple ID in Xcode? Is there a way I can bypass logging into Xcode with my Apple ID

Comment: You can generate the ipa and then use the [App Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)

Answer (score 0):

*Is it mandatory to login with Apple ID registered on iTunes Connect?*

**Yes**

*Do I have to login to Xcode?*

**No**

You can install Apple's Transporter app from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/transporter/id1450874784) to bypass logging into Xcode. You'd still need to login with your Apple ID in the Transporter app.